# Is it possible to order by two fields in a given table,one in ascending and the other in descending order at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently, I have come across a question that has been asked in an interview which states that:

> You have mysql database with a table students. Write a query string to
>   select all the items of the table students and order by two fields one
>   ascending and the other descending.

Let's have a table "students" for example:

[image]

From this example, if we order by ***Score*** in descending order then there is no way to order by ***roll_no*** in ascending order at the same time.

From the point of view of the question, can there be written any query to obtain the desired result Or is the question ambiguous or wrong or my approach to the understanding of the question is wrong?

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY col1 ASC, col2 DESC`.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out????

Comment: Because I think the question is ambiguous. @Eric

Comment: It could be just the wording, but the question sounds wrong. You do not order fields, you order rows by their field values. You _could_ order fields, but it would be rather complicated and destroy meaningful information about the rows.

Comment: In your example table above, add some more students ---ann roll=1 score=60,  and also  ben roll=2 score=60  ...  then sorting desc/asc gives different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your order by you have asked system to order by First column first so it have ordered then you have asked it to order by second column so it have

-> It have to keep ordering of first column.

-> Order by second column too

So it does ordering within group means if

```
Table Test 
 A| B
 --------
  1  1
  1  3
  1  2
  2  2 
  2  4


Select * from test order by A desc, B asc 
Output 
Table Test 
 A| B
 --------
 2  2 
 2  4
 1  1
 1  2
 1  3
```

So in your case, if you first order by score desc then it will order

1. First, all students according to there scores descending
2. And then if two or more students have the same score say 60 then within that group the students will be ordered according to roll number ascending

Hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `order by` clause, you can specifiy the direction `Asc` or `desc`.

In your example with your sample data, there is no point of order by score, then by roll_no, because there is no duplicate in the score column.

If in your real table there are score wich appeared more than once, you can `order by score desc, roll_no`.
( `asc` is the default value)